# How to add columns mapping with MySqlBulkLoader

Tags: c#, mysql, file

i'am trying to import and save csv file to mysql database so my problem is the data are uploaded but values are not correct like in the file.

my question how to put columns mapping with "MySqlBulkLoader" like with "SqlBulkCopy" ( exemple.ColumnMappings.Add("field1","field3");

here my method just i need how to Add columns mappings :

```html
 MySqlConnection connexion = new MySqlConnection("---");
                var dt= new MySqlBulkLoader(connexion);
                dt.TableName = "tablename";
                dt.FileName = dest;
                dt.FieldTerminator = ";";
                dt.FieldQuotationCharacter = '"';
                dt.Load();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `MySqlBulkLoader.Columns` to the names of the columns in the table you're loading. You need to add one column name for each column in your CSV file; to ignore a column, assign it to a user variable and not assigning it to a column. For example, to map the first column to `field1`, the third to `field3`, and ignore columns 2 & 4:

```
var dt = new MySqlBulkLoader(connexion);
dt.Columns.AddRange(new[] { "field1", "@discard", "field3", "@discard" });
```

Note that in order to discard columns in this manner, you will need to add `AllowUserVariables=true` to your connection string.

Comment: Bro if you're still alive and kicking, can you please give the link from where do you get this info or some documentation please, not doubting you, but i want to understad this better. thankyou

Comment: @ListerineBoi from API docs here: https://mysqlconnector.net/api/mysqlconnector/mysqlbulkcopytype/